# pmatrix spacing

Tags: spacing, matrices

I have had this problem asking me to type pascal's identity on https://texnique.xyz/ . It seems that the formula as given by the problem has larger spacing than my code, but I do not know how to correct it. My code is:

```
\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}n-1\\k\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}n-1\\k-1\end{pmatrix}
```

Can you give me some help?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the binomial coefficient `\binom{<top>}{<bot>}`:

```
\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n - 1}{k} + \binom{n - 1}{k - 1}
```

[image]